# Add-on NoClassDefFoundError in Android-N

Tags: android, jar, sdk, add-on

I am creating SDK add-on so third party developers can use API in android studio.

I have followed the instructions given in below link for AOSP code.

https://github.com/gibsson/basic_sdk_addon

Note: I am developing it for qualcom msm8909 processor and AOSP code as Android-N.

In add-on i am adding jar that is developed in following path

vendor/test/

I have package name as com.xyz.led;

The result of sdk-add-on archive is generated in out/host/linux-x86/sdk_addon/ path.

In android studio app/libs folder copied jar file  and click "Add as library".

I am getting following error.

```
 Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

If I change scope as Provided it gets compiled but at run time get the below error.

```
>  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                       Process: >
com.teseledapi, PID: 18319
                                                       java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/xyz/led/LedTest;
                                                           at com.teseledapi.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6723)
                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2619)
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2727)
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1478)
                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)
                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.xyz.led.LedTest" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.teseledapi-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.teseledapi-2/lib/arm, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
                                                           at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
                                                           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                                                           at com.teseledapi.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15) 
                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6723) 
                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119) 
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2619) 
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2727) 
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1478) 
                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121) 
                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889) 
                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: "In android studio app/libs folder copied jar file and click "Add as library"." seems suspicious; why are you not installing the add-on via Android Studio's SDK manager? From the link you posted: "Then the location of the file must be added as a User Defined Add-On Site." etc.

Comment: @stkent thanks for suggestion......but with file added as a User Defined Add-On Site still I am getting the error of  NoClassDefFoundError.

Comment: If you look inside the JAR, is the class in there?

Comment: @stkent yes I am getting class and methods after changing jar as provided.

Comment: I am still struggling to find the solution.   
@stkent can you please help me with steps to create sdk add-on.

Comment: This is the best resource I know of regarding SDK addons: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BfFqYkBDwkU